# Will chaining requests speed up TTFB?

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js, asynchronous, axios

I've inherited a huge existing application using laravel and vuejs. The architecture is quite bad, and  not very modular. The trouble I've been having is the application makes 10 + synchronous axios requests to load data for various sections of the website. The data transfered is quite small, but the TTFB is quite long. I'm certain that db queries are performant and the trouble is on the server side.

An example of one request:

```
      axios.get("/calls/get-lead")
      .then(function(response) {
        vm.state = response.data.lead;

        Fire.$emit("AfterLeadEnqueue", {
          lead_id: vm.state.property,
          number: vm.state.property2
        });
        vm.state = newState1;
        vm.getSomething(); // will trigger another axios request
        vm.someState = newState2
```

There's maybe 15 such examples. My intuition is perhaps to "chain" the requests into one simple request and make them asynchronous, but I don't know if this will do the trick or even how to do this. As a bunch of props, state variables, functions need to be triggered or modified. Please could someone advise on the best way to address this problem

I've also included a network log below:
[check the xhr requests' TTFB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQYPm.png)

Comment: It will only speed things up if displaying the page doesn't require this data.

Comment: Trouble is the data is required. If I chain the requests into one request, is it possible to load data into components as if comes and stop page from halting?

Comment: Just the opposite. You should do each request separately, so when its response comes in you can fill in that component. But that means the user will see each component filling in incrementally, which might be unsettling.